# How to return nothing from a method with return type of id

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following method:

```
- (id) insertDictationResultPlaceholder
{
    return nil;
}
```

The Xcode analyzer is barking at me and telling me:

> nil returned from a method that is expected to return a non-null value

So, for a method with a return parameter of `id`, how do I return nothing? Would an empty string be good? What's the nicest solution here?

Comment: According to Apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput/1614466-insertdictationresultplaceholder?language=objc . `Return Value:
A placeholder object to use to identify the dictation results. This value must not be nil.`

Comment: Does [NSNull null] work instead if nil?

Comment: @conarch yes thanks that seems to work and it a solution that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [NSNull null] instead.  Just be cautious when you're checking for it, because it does NOT equate to nil if you try to do a comparison:

```
if ([NSNull null] == nil)
{
    // This code will never run
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to understand why do you want to return nil as a return, Instead you can use the blocks for call back mechanism.

If you want to use function itself, it would be better if you can send empty object(may be array or dictionary or string) based on the return type expected in the function.

Comment: This method is one that's required when implementing UITextInput, and being that I don't use dictation in my app, I have no use for it. I'm not even sure what the expected return type is. Why do you think empty object would be better?